# How to simulate the collision of two sticks, like you see in Angry Birds?

Tags: collision-detection, rigid-bodies

The angry birds buildings seem to be composed of rigid sticks that collide and fall.
I sure would like to know how to do that. I don't mind writing original code but surely someone has figured this out already and made it open source?

Comment: The buildings in angry birds are made of different materials, each with their unique behaviour (physical properties). They differ in reaction to bird, reaction to impact from other material, falling speed, impact power, flexibility, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/). This is an excellent 2D rigid body dynamics library written by Erin Catto. Not only is it open source, there are also a number of very good GDC presentations, explaining the theory behind the code you'll find in the library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AngryBirds uses the [chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) physics library (but I might be wrong with that). Personally I have looked into [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) and chipmunk as 2D physics libraries and I am more convinced by chipmunk.
This is also because the language bindings to Python and other langueges. They just work out of the box. (no pun intended ;) )

Update: seems I have been wrong, AngryBirds is apparently using Box2D.